# case statement dilemma ruby/rails helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm playing around with understanding case statements and using helpers in rails. I had this code in my view

```
<% case %>
  <%  when post.comments.count > 4 %>
    <%= image_tag "fresh.png", size: "28x28" %> 5+ comments
  <%  when post.comments.count > 2 %>
    <%= image_tag "rotten.jpeg", size: "31x31" %> 3+ comments
  <% else %>
<% end %>
```

its a funny piece of code that gives a user a picture of a fresh and or rotten tomato based on how many comments that person has on his or her post. Anyway I wanted to use a helper to case all this jumbled up code out of my view

I made a helper method

```
  def rotten_tomatoes(post)
    case
      when post.comments.count > 4
       image_tag "fresh.png", size: "28x28"
      when post.comments.count > 2
       image_tag "rotten.jpeg", size: "31x31"
      else
    end
  end
```

I want view to show the image_tag and also put out string that says 5+ comments or 3+ comments but when I put in this code

```
  def rotten_tomatoes(post)
    case
      when post.comments.count > 4
       image_tag "fresh.png", size: "28x28"
       "5+ comments"
      when post.comments.count > 2
       image_tag "rotten.jpeg", size: "31x31"
       "3+ comments"
      else
    end
  end
```

only the string prints out in the view and not the image tag sorry anyone know why?

I tried this

```
image_tag("fresh.png", size: "28x28")
```

which produced the same result

and

```
image_tag "fresh.png", size: "28x28",
```

which produced a syntax error

Comment: try `image_tag("fresh.png", size: "28x28") + " 5+ comments"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [A]nyone know why?

Yes. In Ruby, the return value of a piece of code is the last evaluated part. For example, within the code chunk:

```
image_tag "fresh.png", size: "28x28"
"5+ comments"
```

the last evaluated part is:

```
"5+ comments"
```

That is why.

Comment: oh right, do you know how to make it do both the image tag and the string at the same time?

Comment: Add them with `+` as in  Damien Roche's comment.

Comment: do you know how I could add two links such as link_to "delete", post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure" } and link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) in an if statement for a helper at the same time such as if this condition display these two links